# Read The Docs: Change menu-order (.md)

Tags: markdown, read-the-docs

Does anybody know how to change the menu-order when using `.md`?
I can't find it. I know it's possible with other types like `.rst`, but I use `.md`

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Include a mkdocs.yml file in your root directory that contains:

`pages:
- [intro.md]
- [first_part.md]
- [second_part.md]`

see also http://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/configuration/#pages

Answer (score 0):

As per the latest documentation, to change the menu-order, include the following in the mkdocs.yml file:

```yaml
nav:
   - 'intro.md'
   - 'page1.md'
   - 'so_on.md'
```